# "Unable to connect" pgAdmin4 with Amazon RDS. Any solutions?

Tags: database, amazon-rds, pgadmin

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Vbd.png)
I simply cannot figure out how to access my database through pgAdmin4.

More info:

1. The database is available;
2. The database is publicly accessible;
3. The database is part of a security group which allows all in-bound and out-bound traffic from anywhere (I know it's not good practice but it's only for the sake of making this work);
4. The credentials that I'm using are correct

I tried all solutions that I found online and they didn't work.
Does anybody have possible solutions?
Thank you!

Comment: Please do telnet on port 5432 to check connectivity once. Also verify route table of subnet associated with that RDS. And let me know here output.